# How to loop over packages imports into a function definition?

Tags: python, import, iteration

I want to write a function with a good exception handling to make sure all the necessary packages are installed in the working environment. I need to import two or more packages and to make the code reusable I wanted to loop over the packages imports from a dictionary.

Here is my code without the loop:

```
def pkgs_install():
    import subprocess
    import sys

    try:
        import pandas as pd
        print('{} is already installed'.format('Pandas'))
    except ImportError:
        print('{} is not installed and has to be installed'.format('Pandas'))
        subprocess.call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'pandas'])
    finally:
        import pandas as pd
        print('{} is properly installed'.format('Pandas'))

    try:
        import numpy
        print('{} is already installed'.format('Numpy'))
    except ImportError:
        print('{} is not installed and has to be installed'.format('Numpy'))
        subprocess.call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'numpy'])
    finally:
        import numpy
        print('{} is properly installed'.format('Numpy'))

    print("All packages have been imported. You're good to go!")
```

This code works properly but now creating the loop is way harder. I tried a piece of code but I am now stuck. Here is my code:

```
def pkgs_install():
    import subprocess
    import sys
    pkgs = {'pandas': 'pd', 'numpy': 'np'}
    for p in pkgs:
        s = pkgs[p]
        try:
            import p as s
            print('{} is already installed'.format(p))
        except ImportError:
            print('{} is not installed and has to be installed'.format(p))
            subprocess.call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', p])
        finally:
            import p as s
            print('{} is properly installed'.format(p))

    print("All packages have been imported. You're good to go!")
```

Does anybody have an idea of how to solve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please try this method https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module for dynamic imports in python. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against trying to dynamically call `pip` from within a Python program like this. There are 2 reasons:

1. It seems like bad form to make such an invasive change to the users environment. Let the user decide for themself if they want these libraries installed.
2. There are many different configurations possible for the users system, and we cannot possibly account for every conceivable setup<sup>1</sup>. This runs the risk of breaking things and leaving a mess (see point #1)

Let me ask you this: say this module needs some library installed, and discovers that it's not available. Is that recoverable (by some means other than forcing the install of the missing library)? By recoverable, I mean: will the module still be able to do something useful, or will the only outcome be to display an error message and exit? Usually a missing library is a fatal error, since we import things because we need them and not for fun.

If it's not recoverable, then don't catch it. That suppresses useful debugging information that the user would otherwise be able to act on. If you need to catch it (maybe to display a custom error message or to log the exception to a file), then `raise` the same exception at the end of the `except` block.

I think the best thing is to just do the `import` as usual, and if one fails, let the exception get raised. Exceptions are not the enemy, they are not a mark of failure<sup>2</sup>. All they do is pass information about a program state that was not as expected, and there is nothing wrong with letting them bubble up when necessary.

---

**Edit**
In the comments to this answer, OP added some more information, which explains that the true goal of this exercise is to allow a python program to be packaged in a way that makes it useable by someone else without forcing them to install additional modules.

That is a very common need and one that has a very mature and easy to use solution: [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org). It works for multiple target platforms, and support all common versions of Python. It is open source and installable from PyPI:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

It supports matplotlib, numpy, and presumably pandas (while not listed as a [supported package](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages), I have to assume that if the former 2 packages work, pandas will too).

Here is the [official documentation site](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

---

<sub>1: Maybe the module includes a C extension and requires a compiler. Maybe the user has installed a specific version of the library to a non-standard location. Maybe the version your package needs is not compatible with other libraries that are already installed. Maybe [any one of the dozens of things that could go wrong]......</sub>

<sub>2: I should say, *exceptions you have planned for* are not the enemy. Knowing what exceptions might be raised and making the intentional decision to let certain exceptions propagate unhandled is absolutely OK. If a program raises exceptions that are **not** planned for, that's a different story...</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indeed I agree on the fact that nothing is better than a good old import statement but here I was specifically asked to do define imports within a function (as a constraint)... The goal of this exercise was to run a Python app without requiring any installation action from the user. Quite tricky. I am a beginner in computer science but from what I understand it would not be a good idea to loop over the imports. I should maybe stick to the first version I wrote! 
Very helpful, thank you :)

Comment: I updated this answer with an additional section that should help you do exactly what you are after. But to be fair, the question you asked is not what you described here in the comment section. Next time, if you're trying to do X, don't ask about Y just because you belive that Y is a way of solving X. See here: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

you can use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) library to import the modules by name.

```
import importlib
def pkgs_install():
    import subprocess
    import sys
    pkgs = {'pandas': 'pd', 'numpy': 'np'}
    for p in pkgs:
        s = pkgs[p]
        try:
            s = importlib.import_module(p)
            print('{} is already installed'.format(p))
        except ImportError:
            print('{} is not installed and has to be installed'.format(p))
            subprocess.call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', p])
        finally:
            s = importlib.import_module(p)
            print('{} is properly installed'.format(p))

    print("All packages have been imported. You're good to go!")
```

Comment: In the finally block, I see the statement `[package] is properly installed` yet the return value of `subprocess.call` is being completely discarded. Care to explain how you know that the package was installed properly? And in the event that it *isn't* installed properly, this is still going to: (1) report that the package was installed properly, (2) report that "all packages have been imported". This is a very lax attempt at error handling.

Comment: Wait for command to complete, then `subprocess.call` will return the returncode attribute from where you can that either package is properly installed or not.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I tried using importlib and it seems to work quite well! I didn't know this library. Thank you ! :)